# Counting Sort algorithm - take negative and positive integer as input (using Map is not allowed)

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting, counting-sort

As you can see in this code I just did how to sort positive integer numbers using counting sort.  but my requirement is I have to take
the negative and positive numbers as input then have to sort the
array using counting sort. finding the lowest value in the array then
taking input is not allowed. I don't know what will be the logic and solution for this.

note: if I take any negative number in my input. the output shows 0 for that value.

Input:  `9, 8, 6, -7, 2, 1`

output: `-7, 1, 2, 6, 8, 9`

```
int k=0;
void Counting_Sort(int A[],int B[],int n)
{
    int C[k+1];
    for(int i=0; i<=k; i++)
    {
        C[i]=0;
    }
    for(int j=1; j<=n; j++)
    {
        C[A[j]]++;
    }
    for(int i=1; i<=k; i++)
    {
        C[i]+=C[i-1];
    }
    for(int j=n; j>=1; j--)
    {
        B[C[A[j]]]=A[j];
        C[A[j]]=C[A[j]]-1;
    }
}
```

// Driver code

```
int main()
{
    int n;
    cout<<"Enter the size of the array :";
    cin>>n;
    int A[n],B[n];
    for(int i=1; i<=n; i++)
    {
        cin>>A[i];
        if(A[i]>k)
        {
            /*It will modify k if an element
            occurs whose value is greater than k*/
            k=A[i];
        }
    }
    Counting_Sort(A,B,n);
    /*It will print the sorted sequence on the
    console*/
    for(int i=1; i<=n; i++)
    {
        cout<<B[i]<<" ";
    }
    cout<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What are A, B, and n as the inputs to your algorithm? What is k? Do you also have driver code, and can you explain what's going wrong right now?

Comment: I'm concerned that your parameters will not respect that `C` is an **array of 1 int**.

Comment: Why is there 2 arrays `A` and `B` instead of 1? What are you counting from here?

Comment: please show a [mre] and explain what the code is supposed to do and what is wrong with it

Comment: @silverfox please check again i have given the driver code.

Comment: @N.Wouda if I take any negative value then the output shows 0 for that negative number. because the code works only for positive integers. how can i change the code for also negative input.

Comment: c++ doesn't support variable length arrays, you should use `std::vector` instead. Why is `k` a global rather than a parameter of the function?

Comment: @AlanBirtles this code works fine for positive input. but I want how it will also work for negative integer input?

Comment: the usual method is to just add an offset of the smallest number to the array values before sorting and remove it again after sorting

Comment: Not too hard to add the smallest negative int number to each value and then they are all positive.

Comment: *"finding the lowest value in the array **then** taking input is not allowed."* Is **"then"** supposed to be **"when"**? And if it is, then what information do you have about the input that you aren't telling us. Like, is the absolute value of the negative numbers always less than the maximum positive number?

Comment: You could apply counting sort twice; on the first pass only handle non-negatives, and on the second, handle the negatives. Afterwards, merge the positive and negative sorted arrays.

Answer (score 1):

There is a simple solution for this too. Just add `maxValue` (assuming this is the maximum absolute value numbers can have) to all elements, sort them with the count sort, then subtract `maxValue` to get back the original values. Addition makes all of them non-negative.

Answer (score 0):

There's a bit of constraint on this problem, but this can be solve by reversing the negative number back to a positive one, and storing negatives and positives in 2 different arrays. Then you can print the negative array first, after that print the positive array:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;

const int maxval = 10000; //maximum absolute value of each element, you can change this

int positiveArr[maxval+1], negativeArr[maxval+1]; //positive and negative array

int main()
{
    int n; cin >> n;
    memset(positiveArr, 0, sizeof(positiveArr)); //set all value to 0
    memset(negativeArr, 0, sizeof(negativeArr)); //set all value to 0

    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
    {
        int x; cin >> x; //input number;
        if (x >= 0) //if x is non-negative
        {
            positiveArr[x]++; //add count of x
        }
        else
        {
            negativeArr[-x]++; //add count of -x
        }
    }

    for (int i = maxval; i >= 1; i--) //printing the negative array
    {
        if (negativeArr[i] > 0)
        {
            for (int j = 1; j <= negativeArr[i]; j++) {cout << -i << " ";}
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i <= maxval; i++) //printing the positive array
    {
        if (positiveArr[i] > 0)
        {
            for (int j = 1; j <= positiveArr[i]; j++) {cout << i << " ";}
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Result:

```
6
9 8 6 -7 2 1
-7 1 2 6 8 9
```

Another test:

```
19
-7 -9 0 1 -1 4 -3 -2 4 9 1 -9 -7 1 0 9 -7 -2 12
-9 -9 -7 -7 -7 -3 -2 -2 -1 0 0 1 1 1 4 4 9 9 12
```